# Agile web dev with Rails 4: Where does the @cart parameter come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

From Chapter 12 Task 4: Capturing an order.

Where did the @cart parameter from @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)  that is in the Orders Controller come from and what values are being passed through that method?

```ruby
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
end
```

```ruby
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
end
```

LineItem has one-to-many association to both Cart and Order. Since LineItem has an association to both Cart and Order, does that mean that it has access to the instance variable in the Cart and Order controller?

How are they able to access or use the @cart instance variable from other controller that isn't Cart

Additional question

What values are being appended to line_items from 'item'

```ruby
  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end
```

I'm really new to Rails, so I'm not really sure if I'm even asking the right question.

Comment: Have you check the code of form??

Comment: I'm guessing `@cart` is made using product ids that are held in the session - this probably happens the application controller (which the other controllers usually inherit from)

Comment: or maybe it is simply a before_action in the same file

Answer (score 0):

If you do an application-wide search for '@cart' you will most surely find where @cart is being defined. Unless you're using a gem, my bet is that it is being defined in a helper method in one of your controllers. If @cart is used by multiple controllers (makes sense that it would be used by orders_controller, maybe users_controller, maybe products_controller), it might be worth checking in application_controller.